# Flip $n$ coins, discard tails, and continue until $k$ heads remain

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider the following game: $n$ participants have a fair coin each, on a given round, the not already discarded participants flip their coins, those who flip a tail are discarded from the game, the remaining ones continue to play until there are at most $k$ of them left.

The question is: what's the distribution of the number of *rounds* in this game?

**Bonus question:** idem, but the $n$ coins are all unfair, with probabilities $p_1$, $p_2$, $\ldots$, $p_n$.

---

**Disclaimer:** this is *not* a homework question, it came up when considering distributed routing protocols with a colleague.

Comment: The game may not terminate. It should terminate when there are less than $k$ participants left.

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit to take that into account. Anyway, it may still not terminate (with _very_ small probability).

Comment: There's no such thing as the distribution of the expected number. Do you want the distribution or the expected number?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just waking up. I'd like to know the distribution. Will edit :)

Comment: Is this some collision resolution scheme on a shared channel?

Comment: Yup, the channel has capacity $k$, each participant can only detect collisions, they can't be assumed to make fair flips, that's pretty much it :)

Answer (score 1):

Each coin follows a Geometric Distribution $P(X_i=k)=p_i(1-p_i)^{k-1}$ because it has probability $1-p_i$ of showing a head on each of the $k-1$ tries, and then, it has probability $p_i$ of showing tail on the $k$th try.

Then, we are trying to find the distribution of $\max_iX_i$. We have that: $$P(\max_iX_i \leq k)=P(X_i\leq k \forall i)=\prod_iP(X_i \leq k)=\prod_i \sum_{j=1}^k p_i(1-p_i)^{j-1}=\prod_i p_i\frac{1-(1-p_i)^k}{1-(1-p_i)}=\prod_i (1-(1-p_i)^k)$$

Then, I have no good idea on how to continue that, if someone has one...

EDIT: My bad, I just saw that the game stops when less than $k$ players are left. So this is just for the case $k=1$...

Answer (score 1):

The probability that a particular fair coin has not shown tails by the $m$th round is $\dfrac1{2^m}$

So the probability that $k$ or fewer out of $n$ have not shown tails by the $m$th round is $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j} \dfrac{(2^m-1)^{n-j}}{2^{mj}}$

So the probability that the $m$th round is the first time that only $k$ or fewer out of $n$ have not shown tails is $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j} \dfrac{(2^m-1)^{n-j}}{2^{mj}} - \sum_{j=0}^k {n \choose j} \dfrac{(2^{m-1}-1)^{n-j}}{2^{(m-1)j}}$

This is easy enough to calculate using R using

```
pbinom(k, n, 1/2^m) - pbinom(k, n, 1/2^(m-1))
```

and, for example with $n=10$ participants, it would give the following probabilities for varying $m$ and $k$ (so columns sum to $1$, subject to rounding)

```
     k     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 m                 
 0       0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000
 1       0.001 0.011 0.055 0.172 0.377 0.623 0.828 0.945 0.989 0.999 0.000 
 2       0.055 0.233 0.471 0.604 0.545 0.357 0.168 0.054 0.011 0.001 0.000
 3       0.207 0.395 0.355 0.197 0.074 0.019 0.003 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 4       0.261 0.235 0.098 0.025 0.004 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 5       0.204 0.089 0.018 0.002 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 6       0.126 0.027 0.003 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 7       0.070 0.007 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 8       0.037 0.002 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
 9       0.019 0.001 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
10       0.010 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
11       0.005 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
12       0.002 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
13       0.001 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
14       0.001 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
15       0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
```

This could easily be extended to cases where the coins were consistently biased, but would become more complicated if they each had different biases

Comment: If I'm reading the table you gave correctly, it would seem to indicate that there's virtually no chance of having, eg, 10 coins and needing 4 flips to get 7 heads, is that right? It's quite surprising...

Comment: @mpr: An individual has a probability of $\frac{1}{8}$ of three heads so the probability of having $8$ or more out of $10$ with three heads is ${10 \choose 8}\frac{7^2}{8^{10}} + {10 \choose 9}\frac{7^1}{8^{10}} + {10 \choose 10}\frac{7^0}{8^{10}} \approx 0.0000021$. So yes, the probability that you need four or more rounds to get down to the first time there are $7$ or fewer players left is very small.

Comment: @Henry Shouldn't the probability that $k$ or fewer out of $n$ have not shown tails by the $m$th round be $\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j} \left(\frac{1}{2^m}\right)^{j} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^m} \right)^{n - j} = \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j} \frac{(2^m - 1)^{n -j}}{2^{mn}}$ ?

Comment: The comment of @dazedviper is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial approach.** This is not a complete solution.  I'm still thinking about it, but perhaps what I write down may suggest a completion for someone else.

We will be satisfied with arriving at a set of $z$-transforms

$$
P_n(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty
         P(\text{$m$ tosses required to get down to $k$ or less} \mid n) z^m
$$

With this definition, we observe that for $n \leq k, P_n(z) = 1$, while for $n > k$,

\begin{align}
P_n(z) & = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n zP_j(z) \\
       & = \frac{z}{2^n} \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} P_j(z) \\
       & = \frac{z}{2^n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j} P_j(z)
         + \frac{z}{2^n} P_n(z)
\end{align}

Multiplying both sides by $2^n$, then subtracting $zP_n(z)$, we obtain

$$
\left(2^n-z\right)P_n(z) = z\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j} P_j(z)
$$

or

$$
P_n(z) = \frac{z}{2^n-z} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j} P_j(z)
$$

Using our boundary condition, we can "simplify" this to

$$
P_n(z) = \frac{z}{2^n-z} \left[ \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n}{j}
                              + \sum_{j=k+1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{j} P_j(z) \right]
$$

but I'm not sure this is the proper way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Let these participants have an unfair coin each with probability of heads equal to $p$.
Suppose that after $m$ rounds there are exactly  k participants left.

Let's introduce the sum

$$S_k=X_1+X_2+...+X_k$$

where $P(X_i=1)=p$ and $P(X_i=0)=q=1-p$

For a fixed $k$ the generating function of $S_k$ is

$$(q+ps)^k$$

Now, actually $k$ changes from round to round, that means $k$ is a random variable (independent of the $X_i$).

Let $p(m,k)$ be the probability that after $m$ rounds there are exactly  k participants left.

Let $Z_m(s)$ be the generating function of $p(m,k)$. Then we have a simple recurrence relation

$$Z_{m+1}(s)=Z_m(q+ps)$$

with $Z_1(s)=(q+ps)^n$

Now, in principle we can calculate the generating functions sequentially. But much more interesting is to compute the expected number of participants  after $m$ rounds, $E_m=Z'_m(1)$.

Differentiate the recurrence relation with respect to $s$ and set $s=1$ to get

$$E_{m+1}=pE_m$$

Since $E_0=n$ we obtain

$$E_m=np^m$$

How many rounds are needed to have $E_m=1$?

$$m=-\frac{\ln n}{\ln p}$$

For example if $n=1000$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$ (fair coin) then $m≈10$

In fact, I thought that number was higher. Maybe someone can run a simulation model to check this result?